# Narrowing down arguments in implementations

Tags: java, interface

For training purposes I am creating Java project that will hold information about animals. There is an abstract class Animals which other will extend.

I would like to create carnivorous interface that in general will take any animal as an argument:

```
    public interface Carnivorous {

        public void eatAnimal(Animal animal);
    //alternative way I have tried
        public <T extends Animal> void eatAnimal2( T animal);
    }
```

Problem is that in specific implementation I would like to narrow it down to specific classes that extends Animal:

```
public class Cat extends Animal implements Carnivorous {


public Cat(String name, int expierence, String meow) {
    super(name, expierence);
    this.meow = meow;
}

public String getMeow() {
    return meow;
}

public void setMeow(String meow) {
    this.meow = meow;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Cat [meow=" + meow + ", name=" + name + ", expierence=" + expierence + "]";
}

@Override
public void eatAnimal(Animal animal) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public <T extends Animal> void eatAnimal2(T animal) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

In this case I want the cat only to eat a mouse. I don't it to be able to eat let's say a zebra.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics in interfaces to help type-checking.

```
public static class Animal {

    public Animal() {
    }
}

public static class Rodent extends Animal {

    public Rodent() {
    }
}

public interface Carnivorous<A extends Animal> {

    public void eatAnimal(A animal);
}

public class Cat extends Animal implements Carnivorous<Rodent> {

    @Override
    public void eatAnimal(Rodent r) {
    }

}
```

Here I have a `Carnovorous` `Cat` that eats only `Rodents`.

Comment: Yes, I had a similar answer in mind but then I asked myself what to do if a cat eats rodents OR mice OR something else with no common super type else than `Animal`. Or-logic cannot easily be expressed by generics.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an interface what Carnivorous can eat.

```
public interface Carnivorous {

    public void eatAnimal(Animal animal);
    //alternative way I have tried
    public <T extends Animal> void eatAnimal2( T animal);

    Set<Class<? extends Animal>> canEat();
}
```

And implementation, andt then check if Carnivorous  can eat provided animal.

```
public Set<Class<? extends Animal>> canEat() {
        //TODO can be moved out of method 
        Set<Class<? extends Animal>> classes = new HashSet<Class<? extends Animal>>();
        classes.add(Mouse.class);
        return classes;
    }
```